# call action in controller from onclick method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a CheckBox like this

```
<td><%= Html.CheckBox("seleccionado", false, new { onclick = "SeleccionarItems();" })%></td>
```

Now, I want to call a specific action from my controller, and pass the value of checkBox How can I do that..

```
   function SeleccionarItems() {
           -- call method to controller and pass value
       }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use jQuery to post to the controller:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: controllerName + '/ActionName',
    data: { 'checkValue': $('#seleccionado').val() },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (jsonData) {
        //This function gets called after posting to the server
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Error!');
    }
});
```

Here is a tutorial that explains the whole process: [Link](http://blog.janjonas.net/2011-08-07/asp_net-mvc_3-jquery-ajax-submit-ajax-form-supporting-unobtrusive-client-side-validation-and-server-side-validation)